# Color Range Associated with Number Range for Markers in Folium

Tags: python, folium

I am trying to have a color range for markers in folium based on a number range in a df column. I got the markers to plot with the following code but I am lost on where to start to assign the color range.

```
m = folium.Map(location=[39.2904, -76.6122],
            zoom_start=12
          )
for index, row in z230.iterrows():
    folium.CircleMarker([row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']],
                    radius=15,
                   ).add_to(m)
```

[z230 print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJJuF.png)

Comment: Can you post a sample of `z230`?   Also, how many unique values are in your number range?

Comment: I added a link to a print out of z230 right below the code above. I would like the color range associated with the numbers in the column 'ClosePrice'

Comment: So you probably have a lot of unique values in ClosePrice I'm guessing.  What about establishing a handful of buckets via [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) and assign some colors based on those buckets?

Comment: Sorry for the basic questions but I understand the pd.cut. I do not understand how to assign the categories to a specific color in the code above.

Comment: Ok, I'll submit an answer and hopefully, that will clarify some things

Comment: I understand, thank you for your help!

Comment: how are we looking?

Answer (score 3):

I'll start by creating a new series/column with `pd.cut()`

I'm using 4 bins and the label arg to return 1 of 4 colors depending on the value of ClosePrice

```
z230['marker_color'] = pd.cut(z230['ClosePrice'], bins=4, 
                              labels=['yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'red'])
```

Below I'm adding a color arg to CircleMarker and passing the marker_color we created above

```
m = folium.Map(location=[39.2904, -76.6122],
            zoom_start=12
          )
for index, row in z230.iterrows():
    folium.CircleMarker([row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']],
                    radius=15, color=row['marker_color']).add_to(m)
```

Comment: Again very helpful, I am running into another slightly more ambiguous issue. When I try to render over 1000 points on the map it returns blank. I am running this in a jupyter notebook and after a little research appears folium has an upper bound to plotting points. I am unable to find a simple fix. I would appreciate any advice on the issue.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for the feedback.  I would accept this answer and submit a new question for the other issue.  PS i've had decent luck with FastMarkerClusters when dealing with larger datasets